# A general strategy to find isomorphisms using Cayley tables

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-isomorphism

Suppose I have two finite groups, then how I can find an isomorphism between them. The reason I am asking is whenever I encounter a problem that requires this, the best I can do is guess and "hope" that I got the right answer. Consider, for example the group $(Z_4, +_4$) and the group $(U_{10}, \times_{10})$ then the Cayley tables of the groups are as below:
[image: Cayley tables]

I also listed the mapping $\phi$ that is an isomorphism from the first group to the second. However, I really don't understand how would one find such mapping without "guessing", what would be the general strategy to obtain this result?

Comment: for one thing, isomorphism must map identity element to identity element; more generally, isomorphism must preserve element orders (so $2\mapsto9$); note that another isomorphism besides the one you listed takes $1$ to $3$ -- there is not only one right answer

Comment: In general, the task of comparing two groups by looking at their Cayley tables, or constructing a group by making up a Cayley table (and checking associativity, etc) is a misguided task. It is far more feasible to (learn and invoke) some structure theorems (e.g., Structure Theorem for Finite or Finitely-Generated Abelian Groups) to have canonical objects to compare to.

Comment: To supplement the advice of @paulgarrett, another good strategy is to literally learn lots and lots of specific groups. Then, when you run across a mystery group, you'll have a lot to compare it to, using various structure theorems.

Comment: Testing two finite groups of order $n$ for isomorphism appears to be a computationally difficult problem, and it is unknown whether it can be solved in time polynomial in $n$. The best know algorithms are $O(n^{\log n})$.

Answer (score 1):

Isomorphisms must preserve element orders.  In particular, they must map identity element to identity element, so in your example $0\mapsto1$.  In your example, one element in each group has order $2$ ($2$ and $9$, respectively), so $2\mapsto9$.  That leaves $1,3$ mapping to $3, 7$, and in fact either $1\mapsto3$ and $3\mapsto7$ or $1\mapsto7$ and $3\mapsto3$  could be an isomorphism.

Answer (score 0):

The best strategy I can think of is by making observations about structure, for example you know the identity has to map to the identity, similarly elements of order n have to map elements of order n. Similar observations allow you to build up an isomorphism piece by piece.