# Is $Z^*_5$ a group of order 4 under modular multiplication? What type is it then(isomorphic to which one)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I read that there is 2 type of group of order 4. 1. Cyclic group of order 4 and 2. Klein-4 group.

My question is $Z^*_5$ does not seem to fit either one of it by just looking at the table of operation but then **why is it a group**? Did I miss any thing or does it actually isomorphic to one?

Thank you the comment below so as you ask me, here is the [PICTURE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rms7b.jpg).
The problem is I don’t see why is $Z^*_5$ under multiplication isomorphic to $Z_4$ under addition. And it would be very kind if someone can provide such bijection for me to be crystal clear to me. Thanks again!

And well, what I mean by looking the same and different is like 0 in $Z_4$ playing the same role as 1 in $Z^*_5$ ,which generator in $Z_4$ is playing the same role as which in $Z_5^*$ and vice versa.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange. The group of invertible elements under multiplication modulo $5$ is cyclic (generated by $2$ or $3$)

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. If you [edit] the question to show us how you "looked at the table of operation" to decide it wasn't a group we may be able to help you find your mistake.

Comment: Thank you for answering! I understand the condition to be a group but I’m just curious that why the table I made looked different to the 2 groups that I mentioned above or is it actually not that different and I just didn’t notice it.

Comment: You just have to view $\Bbb Z/4$ with addition as a multiplicative group of units. So $0$ corresponds to $1$ etc. Then the two group tables can be made the same. The duplicate gives an explicit isomorphism between $U(5)$ and $C_4$ (so is "crystal clear").

Comment: Thank you so much. The thread you provide me is beyond crystal clear and exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3382358/proving-isomorphism-on-additive-group-bbbz-4-and-multiplicative-group/3382820#3382820), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3300911/prove-two-groups-are-isomorphic/3300927#3300927), and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3481069/a-general-strategy-to-find-isomorphisms-using-cayley-tables/3481077#3481077)

Comment: Big thanks again! Mr. J. W. Tanner. And also, it would be kind of you for answering me one more question. 
To give my Prof. such function or a map showing to group are isomorphic, Is it legit to just tell my prof which value map to which without giving a proper function to calculate? It seems find to me but not sure if it Is legit generally.

Comment: defining which element each element is mapped to should suffice to define the isomorphism function

Comment: Just consider the isomorphism determined by sending $2$  in $\Bbb Z_ 5^×$  to $1$ or $3$ in $\Bbb Z_ 4$.  Sending a generator to a generator determines an isomorphism.  There are two different ones.